# Asynchronously Send HTML Email with PHP After Form Submit

Tags: php, jquery, email

I'm trying to make a form that submits the fields asynchronously into a database and then send out a html conformation email to the submitted email address. The db part is working fine but I can't send out the html email (but none html email works, see more info below).

Here's the jquery and php I'm using:

jQuery (this function gets called on click):

```
function commentFio() {
    var name = $('.fio #name_js').val();
    var name = encodeURIComponent(name);

    var email = $('.fio #email_js').val();
    var email = encodeURIComponent(email);

    var telephone = $('.fio #telephone_js').val();
    var telephone = encodeURIComponent(telephone);

    var hkid = $('.fio #hkid_js').val();
    var hkid = encodeURIComponent(hkid);

    var comment = $('.fio #comment_js').val();
    var comment = encodeURIComponent(comment);

    if($('.fio #marketing').prop('checked')) {
        var marketing = '1';
    } 
    else {
        var marketing = '0';
    }
    if($('.fio #term').prop('checked')) {
        var term = '1';
    } 
    else {
        var term = '0';
    }
    var ajaxURL = '<?php echo $campaign_root_directory; ?>/ajax.php?dir=<?php echo $campaign_root_directory; ?>&task=submit_comment&youtuber=fio&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&telephone=' + telephone + '&hkid=' + hkid + '&comment=' + comment + '&marketing=' + marketing + '&term=' + term; 
    $('.video_overlay_wrap .content_wrap').scrollTop(0);
    $(".video_overlay_wrap .fio .vote.block").html(load_gif);
    $(".video_overlay_wrap .fio .vote.block").load(ajaxURL, function() {
        $(".video_overlay_wrap .fio .comment.block").html(load_gif);
        $(".video_overlay_wrap .fio .comment.block").load("<?php echo $campaign_root_directory; ?>/ajax.php?dir=<?php echo $campaign_root_directory; ?>&task=fetch_comment&youtuber=fio");
    });
}
```

PHP (detects the task variable in the url):

```
            // Localize and sanitize
            $youtuber = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['youtuber']));
            $name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
            $email = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']));
            $telephone = preg_replace('/\D/', '', strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['telephone'])));
            $hkid = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hkid']));
            $comment = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['comment']));
            $marketing = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['marketing']));
            $term = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']));

            // Clear default
            if($name==$field_name) {
                $name = '';
            }
            elseif($email==$field_email) {
                $email = '';
            }
            elseif($telephone==$field_telephone) {
                $telephone = '';
            }
            elseif($hkid==$field_hkid) {
                $hkid = '';
            }
            elseif($comment==$field_comment) {
                $comment = '';
            }

            // Set check box value
            if($marketing==1) {
                $marketing = 'I agree to receive promotional material.';
            }
            else {
                $marketing = '';
            }
            if($term==1) {
                $term = 'I have read and agree to the Terms and Privacy Policy.';
            }
            else {
                $term = '';
            }

            // Validate fields
            if($youtuber!='' && $name!='' && $email!='' && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && $telephone!='' && is_numeric ($telephone) && $hkid!='' && strlen($hkid)<=10 && strlen($hkid)>=7 && $comment!='' && $term!='') {
                $insert = mysql_query("
                    INSERT INTO 
                        comment_index (
                            last_update,
                            cookie_id,
                            youtuber,
                            name,
                            email,
                            telephone,
                            hkid,
                            comment,
                            marketing,
                            term,
                            ip,
                            user_agent
                        )
                    VALUES (
                        '$current_time',
                        '$cookie_id',
                        '$youtuber',
                        '$name',
                        '$email',
                        '$telephone',
                        '$hkid',
                        '$comment',
                        '$marketing',
                        '$term',
                        '$ip',
                        '$user_agent'
                    )
                ");
                if($insert) {

                    // Set Email Content
                    $recipient = $email;
                    $subject = "Subject";
                    $message = '
                        this is the first line.<br>
                        this is the second line.
                    ';

                    // Send email
                    $sender = 'Sender Name <info@email.com>';
                    $headers = "From:" . $sender . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n";

                    $mail_result = mail($recipient,$subject,$message,$headers);

                    if($mail_result) {
                        $output = 'Success!';
                    }
                    else {
                        $output = 'Fail...';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $output = 'Error';
                }
```

I think the problem is with `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n";` because if I remove that line, the email gets sent successfully but just not in html format.

Can anyone please help? thanks in advance!

EDIT: A little more info, I tried adding the charset to the mail header before but it did not work. But if I try to use the same code to send the mail NOT asynchronously, it works. So I'm wondering if this have something to do with the async.

Comment: Maybe it's being blocked by a spam filter. Check your mail logs to see if the mail is going out or not.

Comment: I would change the title of your question to be more in line with your actual problem, which is sending HTML email with PHP mail.

Comment: `text/html` should usually have a `; charset=xxx` option after it, maybe the spam filter is blocking it because that's missing.

Comment: It's not getting blocked by spam filter, the $mail_result never returns true with the html header so the email doesn't even get sent

Answer (score 0):

Replace last append operation on headers with this:

`$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";`

You were not specifying the `charset`. Read [this](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails) to understand why it is needed.

Comment: That did not work, the email isn't getting sent at all. The only way I can send is if I remove the second $headers completely.

Comment: try `UTF-8` instead of `iso-8859-1` in charset